# Update value in view which is changed inside a loop by a service

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

My component uses a service which (triggered by the component) manipulates thousands of objects in a loop. As is good practice, I want to include a progress indication for this operation. At the moment, I haven't managed to feed the progress back to the user interface as the loop is running.

Simplified app on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhu7gx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

While the progress is updated in real time in the console (in my app, weirdly enough not on the StackBlitz...) I can't get the progress to update in the view.
What is the proper view to do this? I have tried `ChangeDetectorRef`, running certain things in an `NgZone` and subscribing from the template directly using the `async` pipe, all without any success so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console you will see first nothing is printed out until the synchronous tasks are done and suddenly the browser console prints out all the asyncronous values of your console.log at once.

**In my understanding**
As you are processing a synchronous function, even if the progress value is asynchronously emitted, still the browser engine process the synchronous tasks first and then the asynchronous tasks.

But if you turn your function into a complete async function like using setTimeout and then call your function recursively while you are increasing the progress value each time the function is called, angular will have time to update the view and display the progress value.

```
doLoading() {

    if (this._internalProgress >= 100) return;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.sleep(Math.random() * 300);
      this._internalProgress += Math.random() * 10;

      if (this._internalProgress > 100) {
        this._internalProgress = 100;
      }

      this.doLoading();
    }, 100);
  }
```

You can adjust the timeout value **100** to set the delay time between each chunk execution of you function.

And then in your template just read the _internalProgress value from the service directly, or whatever way you prefer.

```
<p>{{ loader._internalProgress }}</p>
```

Checkout my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8fqgqc?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example